# I want to add next and previous buttons to an enlarged image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating my website portfolio and I have an image that when you click on it opens in another window but enlarged, I want to add next and previous symbols/buttons to that enlarged image so that all the other images can be viewed instead of having to go back and click on the next image etc..  This is my code so far.

```
<div class="grid-item">
<a href="img/6.JPG"><img src="img/6.JPG" width="440" height="180" alt="Building in Paris"></a>
</div>

.grid-item {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
padding: 10px;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
max-height: 200px;
max-width: 460px;
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-item > img:hover{
transform:scale(2.5);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, fyi - no code is available even though you say it is provided

Comment: Please add your html code and css also. or make a demo in codepen.io and jsfiddle

Comment: Initially, I am getting is you will have to apply slider to the big image. Please, upload the minimal code for more clarity.

Comment: I have just added the code, new to this forum, took me a few minutes to figure out how to make my code visible.

Comment: If you think the names is in a sequential manner, then it can be done easily. Like on the click of next, change the path of the image by incrementing the image index. Same for previous.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev, just added the code, it took me a few moments to figure out how to get it to be visible, new to this forum.